# how to write a new line character using binarywriter

Tags: c#

I am using a bianryreader to read the contents of binary file and convert the binary data to a double array.

Contents of binary file

```
Header
Axis values
Points values
```

After the Axis values are written , the points values to be written in a new line.
I am just writing a sample how i am creating a new line

```
BinaryWriter aBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("c:\\newline.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
aBinaryWriter.Write("\r\n");
aBinaryWriter.Close();
```

writing parts works fine.

### Reading part:

I want to read the point values, so I moving the file pointers by 2 location reason to skip the new line character. But What I am seeing is there are 3 characters with the ascii value "2,13,10".

1. What is the reason to have 3 ascii values?
2. How to introduce a new line character("\r\n") in a binary file.

Code:

```
BinaryReader abinRead = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("c:\\newline.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
while (abinRead.PeekChar() != -1)
{
    char aChar = abinRead.ReadChar();
    Console.WriteLine(aChar);
 }
 abinRead.Close();
```

Comment: if you are writing a text file... *why are you using `BinaryWriter`* ?

Comment: but the axis values and points values are written are double but written in ascii values

Comment: Well, you don't show how you write those. But: if you write a double via BinaryWriter, it is 8 bytes of IEEE754: ***not*** ASCII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake here is using `BinaryWriter`. If you are writing a text file, use a `TextWriter`, for example `StreamWriter`:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("foo.txt"))
{
    writer.Write(someString);
    writer.Write(someDouble);
    writer.WriteLine();
}
```

A `BinaryWriter` is only really intended for use with `BinaryReader`, for following a very specific set of binary rules. In most cases even when working with binary, the raw `Stream` is more versatile. But writing a text file via `BinaryWriter` is ... well, *not impossible* (you could do the `Encoding` yourself etc) - but it isn't what it is designed for.

Comment: intenion is write a binary file. Can I use StreamWriter to create binary file.

Comment: @Raghav55 what you are describing, with newlines and ASCII - definitely sounds like text rather than binary - in which case `StreamWriter` is the best tool. If you are trying to write a binary file, but you don't want the rules associated with `BinaryWriter`, then frankly you should just use the raw `Stream` API, and handle all the encoding yourself.

Comment: @Raghav55 perhaps it would help, if you are trying to write a binary file, to simply show the input values and the exact binary file contents you are after.

Comment: for time being let us ignore new line and ascii. My intention is to have a binary file. binary file contents are like this

Comment: header axis 2d points ; header contains the data which is human readable and axis and 2d points are binary data.

Comment: @Raghav55 then either use `Stream` (maybe with some help from `BitConverter`) or `BinaryWriter`. If you want to write some strings into `BinaryWriter` **without** the `BinaryWriter` treatment, then encode it manually (`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)` etc) and pass that to `Write(byte[])`, which *does not* add any prefix.

Comment: once i write the header aBinaryWriter.Writer(header.ToCharArray()); and the axis has to be written in a new line , so i am using binarywriter.Writer("\r\n"); i have to writer 1024 double values ,once this completed again i have to write a the 2d points in a seperate line again i am using binarywriter.Writer("\r\n"); and writing the 2d points and close the file. So the x-axis and 2d points should not be in human readable form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19890/discussion-between-raghav55-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 3):

`BinaryWriter.Write()` writes a *length-prefixed* string.
The first byte is the length of the string.

Comment: when parsing how to parse it? or is there any way to introduce the new line.

Comment: @Raghav55: You can call `BinaryRead.ReadString()`, or you can write bytes or characters directly.

Comment: @Raghav55 you don't *parse* that; you use `BinaryWriter`'s `ReadString`. If you want to write a text file, don't use `BinaryWriter`.

Comment: @Marc Gravell : still I have to use BinaryWriter, but each values to be written @ new line (Axis and points). Is it the correct way to do aBinaryWriter.Writer('\r'); aBinaryWriter.Writer('\n');

Comment: @Raghav55 no, you do not "have to use BinaryWriter". That is the wrong tool for writing a text file.